# Parse strings representing durations

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, timespan

What is the best way to **parse strings representing durations** in .Net ?

e.g. "1s" should be converted to a 1 second timespan, "2h30" to a 2 and a half hours...

I think this is the kind of stuff handled by the ***Moment.js*** library.

Is there something equivalent in .Net, be it provided by the framework or an external library (***Noda Time*** maybe) ?

I'm pretty sure I could do that quite simply with a **regexp** but if I want to develop that quickly I will for sure forget 80% of the patterns the users might use.

Comment: Have a look at [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-datetime)

Comment: You've got also this one [TimeStamper](http://timestamper.codeplex.com/) that seems to do more or less what you are asking for

Comment: @Pikoh Humanizer seems to be great the other way around to convert timespans to strings. But I may have missed something...

Comment: @Pikoh AFAIK, Humanizer does _not_ provide a way to parse `1s` string to value of `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` etc.. It supports only friendly formatting..

Comment: @Pikoh Also looks like TimeStamper has no release in downloads page :)

Comment: @SonerGönül Wow...today is my day. Indeed I've used humanizer but only to format dates i thought it had the other way around. Found Timestamper on google, but didn't realized it did not have any release. So now, time to shut up :)

Comment: @Pikoh All the answers are appreciated, thanks. :)

Comment: @DownVoter Please explain...

Answer (score 0):

.Net provides ways to specify custom formats when parsing date and time datastructures, see if this link might help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'd like to avoid fixing a rigid format.